# Managing global modules with node version manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm, version

I'm using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage versions of node.js / io.js and I run into issues with global modules every time I update node.

I just tried to install `npm i express-generator -g`. I happened to have an older version in `/usr/local/bin` so I removed it.

Now this is happening

```
$ which express
/Users/thomas/.nvm/versions/io.js/v3.2.0/bin/express
$ express
-bash: /usr/local/bin/express: No such file or directory
```

I happen to have many versions of node and io.js that I've installed in the past.

Here's the tree view for `/Users/thomas/.nvm/versions`.

```
.
├── io.js
│   ├── v1.3.0
│   ├── v1.6.0
│   ├── v1.6.2
│   ├── v1.6.4
│   ├── v1.8.1
│   ├── v2.0.0
│   ├── v2.2.1
│   ├── v2.5.0
│   └── v3.2.0
└── node
    ├── v0.12.1
    └── v0.12.4
```

Each version has it's own set of global modules in it's `bin` directory.

I do see an option to reinstall packages `nvm reinstall-packages` but it doesn't fix my express issue above.

I simply want to keep all of my global modules when I switch node versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a `bin` is removed like

```
rm /usr/local/bin/express
```

The shell needs to be restarted.